# Expected number of days where Bob wears matching pairs of socks

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value

> Bob has $7$ different pairs of matching socks. Every day for a whole week, he picks $2$ socks at random, without replacement. After the week, what is the expected number of days that he wore matching socks.

Here is my attempt: Consider the first day. There is a $\tfrac{1}{13}$ chance of Bob wearing matching socks, as given any first sock, one out of the other $13$ socks is matching. Then, by Linearity of Expectation the number of days that he wears matching socks is $7 \cdot \tfrac{1}{13}=\tfrac{7}{13}$ days. Is this correct? I'm doubting myself a little since I am not super experienced with Linearity of Expectation. Can someone please verify my solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Verified**.   That is how Linearity of Expectation works.

Under the reasonable presumption that there is no distinction between left and right socks, and that each sock is equally likely to be selected on any day, then the expected count for days with matching socks is $7/13$.